# Bootstrap v3.2.0 Grid system layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

Ok I'm probably missing something really simple here but I can not figure out why my cols are acting like this using twitter bootstrap. This happens when I resize the browser to about 323px. I have no other css styles or html on the page. I have attached 2 screen shots for reference.

I have my columns set accordingly but when I resize the browser to the smallest size it drops the last col-xs-1 down one row.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1">1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">9</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">1</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: HERE IS THE SCREEN SHOT OF WHAT IT LOOKS LIKE ON FF AT ITS SMALLEST WIDTH]

If I was to have 4 col-xs-3 they display correctly horizontally across the browser.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">3</div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">3</div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">3</div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: HERE IS WHAT IT LOOKS LIKE ON FF SMALLEST WIDTH]

Here is the bootply : http://www.bootply.com/xuVoyvjNKr

What am I missing here ?

Comment: please add bootply.com

Comment: You can copy paste the code in bootply but you wont be able to recreate the scenario because bootply doesnt allow you to resize the window to that width or resolution I am looking to resolve the issue for.

Comment: This is literally the only code. You can just copy the above lines of code and throw it on any page that includes bootstrap in the project and resize your browser.

Answer (score 1):

*It's just a question about mathematic...*

---

> You have 3 x col-xs-1 and 1 x col-xs-9...

**Width of  document** : 360px....

One `col-xs-1` should have a **width of** : 360/12 = **30px**...

But you forgot that the divs col-xx-xx has **padding-right and padding-left to 15px...**

So : The **width of col-xs-1 - padding = 30px - 30px = 0...**

---

### You don't have enough place, so it jumps of one line...

*It's not the case with* `col-xs-3` *because* **360/12*3 = 90px**...

---

If you want you can set the padding to 0 for small views, but the problem will appear again if your screen size is less larger again....